# Is there a way to remove a string character from all the values in a column consisting of strings?

Tags: python, string, dataframe

I have a dataframe with one column consisting of string values like "asdb.sdsb" .
Is there a simple method/function where I can remove the "." in all the values in the column.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html#pandas-series-str-replace):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"col1": ["asdb.asdb", "xyz.xyz"]})
```

Which is dataframe:

```
        col1
0  asdb.asdb
1    xyz.xyz
```

Then:

```
df["col1"] = df["col1"].str.replace(r"\.", "")
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
       col1
0  asdbasdb
1    xyzxyz
```